# linux bash script -> update remote mysql table -> error [0m

Tags: linux, bash

i'm using some bash command to extract the current teamviewer id.

Therefore i use this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
OUTPUT="$(teamviewer --info | grep "TeamViewer ID:" | tr -s " " | cut -d ":" -f$

TEAMVIEWERID="${OUTPUT}"
echo $TEAMVIEWERID

mysql --host=xxx --user=xxx --password=xxx xxx$
update table SET teamviewerID="$TEAMVIEWERID" WHERE client="$1";
EOF

echo "DONE"
```

if i run it:

```
pi@xxx:~/Documents/xxx/tv $ sudo ./tv.sh client_xxx
 4975XXXXX
DONE
pi@xxx:~/Documents/xxx/tv $
```

ok everything seems to be fine **BUT** in mysql i receive the following thing:
**[0m 4975XXXXX**

I'm confused what is happening here...

thx for helping

Comment: there seem to be some typos in your code above. Learn to use http://shellcheck.net **before** you post your code here ;-) . When you use shellcheck, you need to include a proper "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash` . AND avoid the top 10 shell script beginner mistakes by reading https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info multiple times. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters at the beginning (`[0m`) are a so called escape sequence. 
 This specific one is used to clear all terminal formattings.

You can easily strip it by using `sed`.

Just replace your `TEAMVIEWERID=` line with the following:

```
TEAMVIEWERID=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | sed 's/\[0m\s//g')
```

---

**Edit**: If the TeamViewer ID always consists of numbers only, we can strip the unknown character by only allowing numbers:

```
TEAMVIEWERID=$(echo "$id" | sed 's/\[0m\s//g' | sed -re 's/[^0-9]+//g')
```

This will only allow numbers.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: hmm i controlle db entry. I can see that the number is there without the [0m but if i click edit to the entry i can see a square before the number. somekind of unknown sign...seems that there has not been deleted all before the number...any idea?

Comment: Are those teamviewer ID's always numbers only?